# Itemize environment nested in adjustbox

Tags: itemize, framed, adjustbox

I need to emphasize a dashed list of formulae by putting it into the colored box. I tried to use `adjustbox` package and the errors like `"Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item [\bfseries 104:]` were what I've ended up with.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 


\usepackage{mathtext}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{adjustbox, xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} 
\usepackage{icomma} 

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{frame, margin=4pt, bgcolor={rgb}{0 1 1}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\bfseries 104:] $\mathbf{Y}_k=\sin{\frac{\pi kx}l}, k\in\mathbb{N}$. 
        \item [\bfseries 105:] $\mathbf{Y}_k=\cos{\frac{\pi kx}l}, k\in\mathbb{N}$. 
    \end{itemize}
\end{adjustbox} 



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You need to enclose `itemize` list in `minipage` environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{margin=4pt, bgcolor={rgb}{0 1 1}, frame}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\bfseries 104:] $\mathbf{Y}_k=\sin{\frac{\pi kx}l}, k\in\mathbb{N}$.
        \item [\bfseries 105:] $\mathbf{Y}_k=\cos{\frac{\pi kx}l}, k\in\mathbb{N}$.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**
Consider is OP comment

**Edit (2):**
Taking into account the comment of the author of the nice and versatile package `adjustbox` the above MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-8pt,  % <---
                  margin=4pt, bgcolor={rgb}{0 1 1}, frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\bfseries 104:] $\mathbf{Y}_k=\sin{\frac{\pi kx}l}, k\in\mathbb{N}$.
        \item [\bfseries 105:] $\mathbf{Y}_k=\cos{\frac{\pi kx}l}, k\in\mathbb{N}$.
    \end{itemize}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before!

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution. By the way I wanted to make the outer frame so that everything inside would be blue. Just swapped `frame` and `margin` keys

Comment: @Rubisko, I was focused only on problem with list. Now is frame moved on fill border, as you say in your comment. You may now to consider to accept answer (by click on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: Note that you can use the `minipage` key of `adjustbox` here: `\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-8pt,margin=4pt, bgcolor={rgb}{0 1 1}, frame}`. Might not be available in 2013 when the answer was original written.